# Get List of all dependency names(even multi-level inheritance) from the template string in FreeMarker

Tags: java, templates, freemarker, template-engine

I was trying to use the FreeMarker template engine in a personal maven project.

I wished to ask if FreeMarker has a public method, which, given the template body as a string can return the list of all the dependency template names (that use #import and #include directives).

If so, can you please point me to the right part of the codebase related to this?
Even if there's no such public method, can you please point me to the private method that accomplishes this?

I'm not sure if there is a way to change name of a directive in any way in FreeMarker(like aliases in bash? Or the "using" declarations in C++, or perhaps any user defined directive in FreeMarker).
If there is, writing such a simple parser could have bugs because if it does not find `<#import>` or `<#include>` directives, we will get no dependency template names, as the alias or user-defined directive.

So are there any such things that I need to pay specific attention to? Or can I write a simple parser of my own using `String.indexOf()` and `String.substring()` methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker does pretty much everything on runtime (except basic parsing), including the resolution of `#include`-s and `#imports`. So you can have things like `<#include someVariable>`, `<#if condition><#include "this.ftl"></#if>`, etc. Therefore it's generally not possible to tell what dependencies a template have, and so there's no private API for that either. There's a non-published API to walk the AST (starting out from `Template.getRootTreeNode()`), and then you can try to guess, hoping that your templates aren't tricky in this regard. (Yes, it's `@deprecated`, but never mind, at this point it very certainly won't be ever removed from 2.x.)

Regarding aliases. Macros, functions, metods are all just values for the template language. So you can do `<#assign mm = myImport.MyMacro>`, and then just use `mm` as you would use `myImport.MyMacro`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer @ddekany ! Understood.

Comment: Is there a way I can get the names of the imported and included templates without writing my own parser?
Thanks! @ddekany

Comment: @RakshitKumar Yes, starting out from the return value of `Template.getRootTreeNode()`, you can traverse the AST. Though it will be awkward (and some classes are possibly package-visible), it's still easier than writing your own parser.

Comment: I don't think I completely understand that. After getting the root tree node, I'd still have to write a regex or string parser to get all the names of the involved(imported and included) templates, right? I meant to ask if there could be a way to not use this regex/string parser and still get a list of all the involved templates. Thanks! @ddekany

Comment: Check said API. The AST is the output of parsing, you don't need to parse anything at that point. It's not a very friendly API for sure... You need to looks for `freemarker.core.Include` and/or `freemarker.core.LibraryLoad` objects in the AST.